# Partial spline. Reference

Tags: splines, smoothing, filter

I have a well done and perfectly working protocol to smooth my experimental data. I do the following:

I have a variable of size 1000. Iteratively I choose random 100 points and spline them using the cubic algorithm. After this I have a number of splines, the result of this 'smoothing' is an average spline. The problem is that it is absolutely self-made protocol.

**Could you help me with a reference for a such approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your described methodology appears as an implementation of [*bagging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating); it is usually seen as a variance reduction technique. Bagging commonly utilises regression or classification trees as base-learners but using a cubic spline is also perfectly fine; the Wikipedia link shows a use-case where the base learner in LOESS smoother. In short, when implementing bagging we combine $B$ approximating functions (learners) $f_b(X)$, $b = 1, \dots, B$ which are train on $B$ bootstrap samples of the training data set. Our final bagging predictor is then the average $f(X)_{bagging} = \frac{1}{B} \sum_1^B f_b(X)$.

Two standard paper references are: 1. Breiman (1996) *[Bagging predictors](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00058655.pdf)* and 2. Bühlmann & Yu (2002) *[Analyzing bagging](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1031689014)*. If you prefer books, Berk's book [*Statistical Learning from a Regression Perspective*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Statistical-Learning-Regression-Perspective-Statistics/dp/3319440470) has a short but very clear and insightful chapter (Chapt. 4) on bagging too.